# Sometimes,Receiver content keeps loading and non error. [Chromecast]

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I send the local file by NanoHTTPD in Android.

I send an URL to the Chromecast. Till the video end, it automatically send another URL to the Chromecast. Sometimes it keeps loading forever. In this situation, I send any URL to the Chromecast it will return "success", but the Chromecast still loading forever,and try to use other APP is the same situation. "REBOOT", is now the only way that can solve this problem.

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(trackURL).setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED).setContentType("video/mp4").setMetadata(metadata).setCustomData(custonObject).build();
remoteMediaPlayer.load(googleApiClient, mediaInfo, true).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {

@Override
public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
    if (mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Log.d("ChromecastController", "video play!");
    } else {
        Log.d("ChromecastController", "video fail!");
    }
}
});
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJsQA.png

Comment: The image of the log you showed doesn't seem to include any errors. When that problem happens, you need to capture the log and present that here. In addition, the success result in load() method doesn't mean that the video is actually loaded.

Comment: This problem doesn't happen after updating the Chromecast . Thank you a lot!